# swift: unwrapping associated types for json request

Tags: json, swift

A large API currently has a filter parameter which can be an array of either [String], [Float], [[string: String]] or [[String:Float]].

I set a Codable request structure with the filters property itself being:

```
public struct MASTJsonFilter:Encodable {
    let paramName:String
    let values:FilterValues
    var separator:String?
    var freeText:String?
}
```

The Codable FilterValues is an enum that wraps a variety of possible types, but I've reduced it down to below:

```
public enum FilterValues {
    case qValue(QValue)
    case qArr([QValue])
    case qDict([String: QValue])
}
```

Where QValue can be one of String, Float, Double, Bool, Int.

I'm trying to "unwrap" those values when i launch the request and set the json.

When encoding any of those combinations of json structures, I get the associated enum wrapping the value. Example:

```
{"timeout":3,"format":"json","pagesize":100,"params":{"columns":"*","dec":-4.09933,"filters":[{"values":[{"string":{"_0":"NUV"}},{"string":{"_0":"FUV"}}],"paramName":"filters","separator":";"},{"values":[{"int":{"_0":3}},{"int":{"_0":4}}], ...
```

The above is the output when the json is decoded before the string is formatted in web utf-8 encoding. As you see, each QValue wraps the associated type.

I am trying to unwrap the associated type for each of these Qvalue instances.

Comment: Why `QValue`? If you have four concrete types use them for the associated values.

Comment: QValue because, as stated in the question, each can be any single, array or dict of int, float, string, bool etc. The question here is, how do I get the decoder to automatically unwrap the associated type of the enum when decoding?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had to apply the same coding key to the QValue enum and make it conform to both Encodable and Decodable. Works like a charm. Here is the code for the QValue enum:

```
public enum QValue {
    /** Quantum value which collapses to a working type
     for codable Json structs
     */
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
    case float(Float)
    case bool(Bool)
}

extension QValue:Codable {
    private enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey {
        case values = "values"
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let singleContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        
        let values = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .values)
        switch values {
        case "int":
            let int = try singleContainer.decode(Int.self)
            self = .int(int)
        case "string":
            let string = try singleContainer.decode(String.self)
            self = .string(string)
        case "float":
            let float = try singleContainer.decode(Float.self)
            self = .float(float)
        case "bool":
            let bool = try singleContainer.decode(Bool.self)
            self = .bool(bool)
        default:
            fatalError("Unavailable data type")
        }
    }

    init(value: String) {
        if let int = Int(value) {
            self = .int(int)
            return
        }
        if let float = Float(value) {
            self = .float(float)
            return
        }
        if let bool = Bool(value) {
            self = .bool(bool)
            return
        }
            self = .string(value)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var singleContainer = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        
        switch self {
        case .int(let int):
            try singleContainer.encode(int)
        case .string(let string):
            try singleContainer.encode(string)
        case .float(let float):
            try singleContainer.encode(float)
        case .bool(let bool):
            try singleContainer.encode(bool)
        }
    }

    public var value:Any {
        switch self {
        case .string(let str):
            return str
        case .float(let ft):
            return ft
        case .bool(let b):
            return b
        case .int(let n):
            return n
        }
    }
    
}
```